# How to call Dialogflow Rest API with OAuth access token

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I have created project in google console
Enable the Dialogflow API
Created OAuth v2 credential
Using this credentials i called access token api to generate token

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?
 scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/dialogflow&
 access_type=offline&
 include_granted_scopes=true&
 response_type=code&
 state=state_parameter_passthrough_value&
 redirect_uri=http://localhost&
 client_id= **i placed client id here**
```

I received access token and passed it to Dialog flow API

```
https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/**PROJECT-ID**/agent/sessions/123456:detectIntent
Header
Content-Type : application/json; charset=utf-8
Authorization : Bearer **ACCESS_TOKEN**

Body
{
  "query_input": {
    "text": {
      "text": "I know french",
      "language_code": "en-US"
    }
  }
}
```

Still i am getting this error

"error":{"code": 401, "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See [https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",…}](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.%22,%E2%80%A6%7D)

i am not able to identify where i went wrong

Please help thanks in advance

Comment: Your example is requesting an OAuth Code (which is not an Access Token). You then need to exchange the code for the OAuth tokens.

Comment: Thanks for reply John, How to get OAuth token from that code

Comment: Hey John Hanley thanks, you were right, i figured out how to generate access token from  OAuth code

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer.

Answer (score 4):

The code that i was passing in api was the OAuth Code(Thanks John Hanley)

API to generate Access token from OAuth Code

```
Post : https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
{
  "code":"OAuth Code",
  "client_id":"Client ID",
  "client_secret":"Client Secret",
  "redirect_uri":"http://localhost",
  "grant_type":"authorization_code"
}
```

In response you receive this

```
Response
{
"access_token": "Token",
"expires_in": 3599,
"refresh_token": "Refresh Token",
"scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/dialogflow",
"token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

Pass this access token in header of google API